# Open visual studio project in its respective version instead of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Ever since I installed Visual Studio 2017, it now wants to be the one to open all of my projects. Before installing 2017, if I double clicked a VS 2010 .csproj or .sln in Explorer (Windows 10), it would open in VS 2010. But now opening a project for all previous versions opens in 2017. Even if I right-click and choose Open With > Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector it always chooses 2017. To open it in the correct version of Visual Studio, I have to first open VS and then browse to the project to open. This is a pain when I don't remember which version the project should open with and just want to click it and open it. Can I reset it to open a project in the version of visual studio it belongs with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed how this is meant to work with the team. The only requirement is that you set *Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector* as the *Default App* for .SLN files in Windows. That app launches the version of Visual Studio specified in the solution file. If you crack open a .sln file in an editor, you'll see a section that specifies the version of VS that should be used. It'll look something like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.25909.2
```

One thing to keep in mind though is that value will change whenever a different version of Visual Studio writes to the solution file. E.g., if you create a solution in VS 2010, close VS 2010, launch VS 2017, open the same solution, add a project to it (this is what forces VS to make a change to the .sln file), the version in the solution file will then change to VS 2017. I.e., the last version of VS to write to the solution file, will be set as the version to be used when opening it.

If you're finding it's not working as described, we likely have a bug here. Let me know if that's what you think is happening.

Comment: Well, I could swear I tried Open With > Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector multiple times on different occasions and they still opened with VS 2017, so I didn't even check whether it was set as the default. I set it as the default and it works as expected as does Open With... Thank you.